# API for getting visitors statistic of heroku app

Tags: heroku

Does heroku have an API for getting visitors statistic to my web app hosted on their site?
i don't really want to use Google analysis.

Answer (score 0):

No it doesn't.  Google (uh) for alternatives if you don't want to use Google Analytics - there are quite a few.